# Explicitly Setting the keys when inserting in firebase

Tags: firebase

I have used the following code to insert a new record into firebase

```
var fireBaseRef = new Firebase("https://todoredux1.firebaseio.com/todos");
var newObjRef = fireBaseRef.push();
newObjRef.set({'id': nextId, 'text': text, 'complete': false});
return dispatch(addLocalTodo(nextId, text));
```

it works but my data looks like

[image]

Earlier my keys were integers (1, 2, ... 6) but now the keys looks funny.

The problem is the funny keys is that when the keys are integers the query results returns a nice array of objects

[image]

but as soon as the records with funny keys are entered. the structure of the query results changes to

[image]

The code i use to query the data is

```
    var fireBaseRef = new Firebase("https://todoredux1.firebaseio.com");
    fireBaseRef.child('todos').once('value', function(todosRef){
        return dispatch(receiveTodosSuccess(todosRef.val()))
    }, function(errorText) {
        return dispatch(receiveTodosFailure(errorText))
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.push` you'll have those *funny keys*. You need to use [child](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/child.html) and then [set](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html). In order to set the keys you want, you may do something like this:

```
// ...
newObjRef.child(nextId).set({'id': nextId, 'text': text, 'complete': false});
```

If you use `.child(nextId)` you will create a key with the `nextId` value and solve your problem.

That said, It may not have to much sense to use `.push` and then `.set` because of you'll create a *funny key* and then define it value. Maybe this would be a better approach to achieve what you are looking for:

```
// Define your Firebase reference. 
var fireBaseRef = new Firebase("https://todoredux1.firebaseio.com/todos");

// Set some data with the key you want.
newObjRef.child(nextId).set({'id': nextId, 'text': text, 'complete': false});
```

Hope it helps.